# regex or operator in validation

Tags: regex

in Regex i am using the following to validate an email adress:

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2}\b
```

in this last part

```
.[A-Z]{2}\b
```

I am trying to for example select the emails that end with`.It` or `.De` or `.Fr` only and ignore any other endings.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

- a literal dot `\.`
- a look behind with ignore-case
- end of input `$` anchor

Like this:

```
.*(?<=\.(?i)(it)|(de)|(fr))$
```

Comment: This allows endings of `.uk` or `.de` etc which are to be ignored.

Comment: @jerry thanks - I misread the question (thought he wanted all emails with .xx ending). Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only select those domain names, use a non-capturing group:

```
\.(?:it|de|fr)
```

Comment: @user1590636: You shouldn't do that in the regex. What language are you using?